# Cannot create mapping on elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

I want to create an index on elasticsearch and i want to create a mapping.

What i have understood about mapping is this is an optional step before inserting data to define fields types.

Index creation:

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/idx5"
```

Mapping creation:

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/idx5/_mapping" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "properties": {
        "element_type": {
            "type": "keyword"
        }
    }
}
'
```

Now, i get this error when trying to insert data in index

```
[type] => illegal_argument_exception
[reason] => Rejecting mapping update to [idx5] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [_doc, doc]
```

If i do not create mapping, i have no error.

Any idea ?

Thanks

** EDIT **

Version of Elastic search: 6.2.4

** EDIT **

Here is how i am trying to insert data:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:9200/idx5/doc/ -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{
         "id" : "1234",
         "element_type": "TYPE1",
          "title" : "test"
     }
     '
```

Comment: which es version you are using?

Comment: 6.2.4 see my edit

Comment: thanks, looking into it

Comment: I have add how i am trying to insert data

Comment: thanks, can you use this URL `http://localhost:9200/idx5/_doc/`  to add the data

Comment: Sorry, it is ok with _doc. But i do not understand why i should put _doc ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210813/discussion-between-opster-elasticsearch-ninja-and-bob5421).

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/70922185/4845324 . it's your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using the Elasticsearch version 6.X, which doesn't support more than one `type` in a single index and by default, if you don't specify it creates `_doc` type, which as you didn't specify at index creation, it will use `_doc` type.

Now while indexing instead of using `_doc` you are using `doc` which means Elasticsearch thinks you are using another `type` name for your index and as it's not supported Elastic throwing an error(**even specifying the names of types in your index , which are `doc` and `_doc` in this case**).

Just replace your the URL in your index doc request to  `http://localhost:9200/idx5/_doc/` and it should work.

**Please read the [elastic doc for removal of type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/removal-of-types.html#_schedule_for_removal_of_mapping_types) and what version has what changes.** And specific to Elastic 6.X

> Indices created in 6.x only allow a single-type per index. Any name
>   can be used for the type, but there can be only one. The preferred
>   type name is _doc, so that index APIs have the same path as they will
>   have in 7.0: PUT {index}/_doc/{id} and POST {index}/_doc

Comment: How can i create 'doc' type instead of '_doc' default type ?

Comment: at index creation only, but note, its would require a request body and POST method

Comment: @Bob5421, please follow this link https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/indices-create-index.html#mappings , here you can even copy the `curl` command which you are using and change the `type1` of sample to your `doc` or whichever type name you want to use 

Comment: I have copy/pasted the example and it gives me this error: ""Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [type1 : {properties={field1={type=text}}}]""